# Get title of accordion with GTM / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager

My HTML:

```
<div class="children-group paragraph paragraph--type--services-child-accordion">
          
    <div class="accordion-tab">
        <h3>Body</h3>
        <img class="icon-angle-down" src="">
        <img class="icon-close" src="">
    </div>

    <div class="stuff-inside-accordion">...</div>

</div>
```

My custom variable in GTM:

```
function(){
    var title = {{Click Element}}.closest('.paragraph--type--services-child-accordion').find('h3').text();
    return title;
}
```

I'm trying to pull in the text in the  on a click event. However, I'm getting undefined back on my custom variable. Unfortunately, I can't just use the **{{Click Text}}** variable because the **h3** only occupies a small portion of the clickable area. Clicking anywhere inside **div.accordion-tab** triggers the accordion to open. For example, if you click between the **h3** text and the arrow img icon, the **{{Click Element}}** registers as **div.accordion-tab**. If you click directly on the **h3**, the **{{Click Element}}** registers as the **h3**, as you'd expect. Regardless of where I click within the clickable area, I want to return the text value of the **h3**.

Comment: Why can't you use `.accordion-tab h3`? Like: `.closest('.accordion-tab').find('h3')`

Comment: Can`t you just pass an id to ``h3``?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I've tried that. Still comes back as undefined.

Comment: try : `{{Click Element}}.find('h3').text()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using another technique, and was able to get it to work. Here's the code I used:

```
function(){
  return google_tag_manager["GTM-XXXXXX"].dataLayer.get("gtm.element").parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("div.accordion-tab > h3").innerText
}
```

This method is recommended by MeasureSchool: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=26JfSV_LUzA